# Anchor Tag for Html <TD>

Tags: html, css, anchor, dreamweaver, html-email

I am coding in html-email.  There is a `<td>` with inline CSS code. What I have to do for attach an anchor tag on whole `<td>`.  Please tell me how can I do it. I have tried many options but these are not valid.

```
<td valign="top"  width="204" class="leftColumnContent" mc:edit="left_column_content" align="center" bgcolor="#dee0e2" style="border-left:6px solid #FFF; border-top:5px solid #FFF;"">
    <div align="center" style=" margin-top:10px;">
        <img src="" width="119" height="199" style="max-width:180px;" mc:label="image" />
    </div>
    <p style=" margin-left:20px; width:80%; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;"> <strong>Text here </strong><br />
        <br />
        text here</p>
    <div style="width:80%; margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:15px;">
        <div align="left" style="float:left;"><strong> read more</strong></div>
        <div align="right">
            <img align="none" height="20" id="headerImage2" mc:allowdesigner="" mc:allowtext="" mc:label="header_image" src=".." style="max-width: 55px; width: 55px; height: 23px;" width="55" /></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Dreamweaver is correct.  `<a>` tags cannot contain `<table>`s.  However, it may work anyway.

Comment: but that  does not work for emails  , how do i add it for <td> not sorry it was td not table ..

Comment: I agree, give it a try and see if it actually works.  If you really need click functionality for your whole element, that can always be added with Javaascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot have `<a ...><td>...</td></a>`, by HTML rules. You can nest them the other way around,  `<td><a ...>...</a></td>`. If you need to make the entire cell clickable, then you need to style the `a` element so that it occupies the entire cell. The way to do that depends on context, but if the `td` element has fixed dimensions, then set the following on the `a` element inside it:

```
display: block; height: 100%;
```

Comment: thats good suggestion will it be valid ? if i test if for email on acid

Comment: @JavaStudent, valid in which sense? The HTML markup is surely valid.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the onclick property at the place of Anchor Tag in your table (code).

the Table example is as follows

```
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="javascript:alert('your HTML');">HTML Code is here</td>
    </tr>   
  </table>
```

at the place of `alert("")` you can use `window.location("")`
for send the page redirection on another page.

Comment: Can not use javascript in html-email unfortunately

Comment: issue is that that is useless in emails ,